# List 10 main CPU-consuming process

Tags: process, cpu, ps, top

Unlike [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/show-top-five-cpu-consuming-processes-with-ps), I'd like to list the 10 main CPU-consuming process, how **not in instantaneous CPU usage %**, but rather, **CPU usage since boot** ?

i.e. a process that peaks at 50% CPU during 10 seconds won't be listed and a process constantly using 3% CPU during hours would be listed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get a view of the processes usage since up time, then with `top` you can set it to sort by TIME+ with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  You can also highlight that column with <kbd>x</kbd>.

Sample:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ 

COMMAND                                    
 4046 fred      20   0 1873812 825068 119016 S   0.7 20.4  31:52.12 firefox                                    
 2661 root      20   0  401200  97064  52196 S   5.0  2.4  15:07.41 Xorg                                       
 4058 fred      20   0  438056  25568  19388 S   1.0  0.6   1:30.85 panel-29-weathe                            
 4057 fred      20   0  307456  17904  15628 S   0.7  0.4   0:43.47 panel-21-system                            
 3957 fred      20   0  176732  23596  17536 S   0.3  0.6   0:38.32 xfwm4                                      
 4096 fred       9 -11  436876  14204   8936 S   0.0  0.4   0:37.12 pulseaudio                                 
 5052 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:28.04 kworker/2:2
```

Comment: Can I start like this from command line with `top ....`  ? Because I also want ot use it with Android-rooted-device, and I can't do SHIFT T.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux:

```
ps --sort -time -ef | head -n 11
```