# Is there a way of seeing the CPU usage of the programs in crontab?

Tags: cron, top

I have a 30+ scripts that are run by the crontab at certain intervals, varying from every 30 minutes to once a month. I would like to know if I can see how much drain they cause when they are running?

**Q:** Is there a way of seeing the CPU usage/drainage caused by the scripts running by the crontab?

**Tried:** So far the use of the `top` command, which lists everthing and not specifically the crontab scripts.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -o user,uid,pid,pcpu,pmem,tty,command --sort=-pcpu $(pidof chrome)
    USER       UID   PID %CPU %MEM TT       COMMAND
    gv        1000  1874  5.4  5.4 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome
    gv        1000  1919  4.9  3.8 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --channel=1874.0.533630227 --mojo-application
    gv        1000  3327  3.3 11.6 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  3036  2.7  5.6 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  3681  2.2  3.7 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  1967  1.1  4.7 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  4376  0.6  2.7 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  1991  0.1  2.2 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  2356  0.1  2.4 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  1885  0.0  1.1 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
    gv        1000  1891  0.0  0.2 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
    gv        1000  1921  0.0  0.3 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-broker
    gv        1000  1971  0.0  1.6 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  1979  0.0  1.6 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  1988  0.0  1.8 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
    gv        1000  1996  0.0  1.7 ?        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --touch-events=enabled --enable-features=BlockSm
```

Replace chrome with your script's name.
Use comm instead of command so COMMAND will be printed in short description.
For more options see man ps.

Also check this post: [Show top five CPU consuming processes with `ps`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/show-top-five-cpu-consuming-processes-with-ps)